# ¿Cómo en postman, se podrían realizar diferentes peticiones http pero con el mismo req.user, para node.js?

Tags: nodejs, http, postman, requests

Realizo una petición http a mi 'app_server local', **.../api/login** esto devuelve un objeto json como este:

```
{user: {name: 'john doe', email: 'emailx@gmail.com'}, token: 'sadsddkadDSgjdglgfdfg...', message: 'usuario logueado'}
```

antes de enviar el json, en el backend, se crea el req.user, donde guardo el '_id' y el 'role' de este usuario, información que va en el token adherida.

Necesito realizar otra petición de este mismo usuario, que devolverá más información,  a (****.../api/profile****, también envío en la cabecera el token **['Authorized Bearer' token]**).
En el servidor miro el token y por supuesto, coincide el '_id', pero necesito comprobar además, que el usuario que realiza la petición, es el mismo que envía el token. Porque ese token lo puede interceptar otro usuario 'Man in the Middle' y hacerse pasar por el primer usuario, sin serlo, por ello compruebo que el req.user es el mismo.
Sin embargo cuando hago una petición y luego la otra, postman no tiene un mecanismo para decirle que pertenecen al mismo usuario --> req.user, puesto que son diferentes peticiones y el server detecta que no es la misma req.
¿Alguna idea de como testear esto desde postman?, para no tener que realizar todo el frontend y ver si funciona.
No pongo código ni archivos, pues mi pregunta es más conceptual genérica, para todo tipo de lenguajes que realicen peticiones http y no es un problema de código sino de cómo solucionar un algoritmo.

Answer (score 0):

Una aproximación podría ser utilizar JWT (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) para asegurarte de que la persona que tiene este token es la persona que esperas.

Una explicación general de este mecanismo es que tu backend API tendrá una clave secreta con la que "firma" todos los tokens que generan. Estos token contienen informacion adicional con la que podras asegurar que ese token pertenece solo a ese usuario.

Solamente las personas que tengan esa clave secreta serán capaces de convertir el token de un string intelegible a algo con sentido.

El la documentación aportada en el repositorio de npm tienes todo lo necesario para poder usarla, cualquier duda no dudes en consultarla para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Me estás diciendo que el usuario en su app frontend, debe tener la clave secreta para cifrar los tokens, no creo que eso sea seguro ni aceptable. El token lo guardaré en el localstorage, pero no se intenta decodificar, eso daría pistas a un hacker de cual es el token y te la puede liar parda en la BD. ¿Has entendido mi cuestión inicial?, yo el jsonwebtoken se cómo funciona, pero debo comprobar que el req.userId == token.payload.sub._id, por si alguien asumió el token de otra persona, rescatándolo de la petición en la cabecera. Claro que entre /loguin y /perfil el req.userId se pierde. Any Idea

Comment: quizás deba crear una session con pasport y afrontar una estrategia local, aunque use el token y lo envíe en las cabeceras para identificar usuarios, la req.session.userId es una comprobación adicional que evita este riesgo de seguridad. si el token es correcto y además la persona que envia el token es la misma que se logueó, entonces si devuelvo auth=true ... next() en el middleware de authentication. No se voy a investigar y si doy con la respuesta la trasladaré a un tutorial.

Comment: No, el usuario en su app solo deberá tener el token que ha firmado el backend. Para el usuario de la aplicación el token que se le ha asignado es lo único que el conoce, no como ha sido creado. Ese token le habilita a utilizar la API (en tanto este autorizado) pero por supuesto que no debe conocer la clave "privada" o "secreta".

Comment: si yo soy el usuario de la app en el frontend y tengo un 'token' que me identifica y me avala como administrador por ejemplo de la app y/o de la BD, que impide a un tercero coger ese token y enviarlo desde su peticion, el token válido y verificado, gracias por tu interés pero creo que no has entendido lo que propong o yo no m e he sabido explicar. un token en la cabecera solo sirve para saber si el token es válido al confrontarlo en el backend con su TOKEN_SECRET, pero esto no me asegura que el cliente que lo entregó era el que se logueó. pueden ser 2pax diferentes. Exceso de confianza en jwt.

Comment: Creo que hay que utilizar una sesión en el req de la petición, o por lo menos utilizar un sistema como passport.LocallStrategy, aquí hay un método llamado ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken() y otro llamado ExtractJWT.fromBodyField(), que extrae el token del body de un formulario, puedes ponerlo oculto como un campo hide, que añadiría un extra de seguridad, pero no eludible. Otra forma más segura, después de haber estado investigando es crear una session con algún paquete como express-session y mongo-connect. No se seguiré indagando y cuando lo tenga pondré la solución aquí. Muchasgracias

Comment: El problema de express-session, es que en producción no guarda la cookie, necesita de un sistema como mongo-connect para que persistan las sesiones en una base de datos (existen otros sistemas dependiendo el SGBD que uses yo uso mongoose para mongodb) , esto es un poco abrupto y bastante difícil de mantener. por eso sigo indagando. para mas info de este tema he visto los siguientes artículos: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html y https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo  pero ya digo un poco farragoso.

Comment: Lo mejor será usar pasport con LocalStrategy y confiar del token usando en producción un http(s) protocolo encriptado.

Comment: Y algunas buenas prácticas de seguridad: helmet, para negar algunas cabeceras que dan excesiva información del propio servidor como 'x-powered-by' o scurf para ataques crossite, etc.

Comment: después de investigar un poco más las opciones más viables son 2: 1. usar cookie-session y mongo-connect para anotar en req.session.userId el id del usuario logueado, posteriormente cuando quiera acceder a una url privada usar un middleware para ver si pasa el jwt.verify(token, TOHEN_SECRET) y comprobar si existe el req.session.userId y además que ese id es el mismo del payload.sub._id anotado en el token. además puedes implementarlo todo con passport.LocalStrategy que contiene métodos útiles para recuperar el token, el cual no solo puede venir por authorization - ('Bearer ') sino que lo ...

Comment: ... sino que lo puedes enviar vía POST en un campo oculto desde un formulario, para posteriormente comparar ambos tokens, el método es: ExtractJWT.fromBodyField(token_hidden) . 2. confiar exclusivamente en jwt y utilizar un sistema alternativo como https (certificado TLS) ayudado de otras buenas prácticas como helmet() para quitar cabeceras innecesarias en las peticiones, csurf para evitar ataques crooss domine